# Is there a way to limit Helm matches from all sources?

Tags: helm

I don't mean `helm-candidate-number-limit`, because it apparently limits candidates from the individual sources, so if you set it to 100 and have two sources and the first source returns 70 candidates and the second 50 then you get 120 candidates regardless of the limit.

I'd like a limit which applies globally that is Helm takes candidates from the first source and if it's over the limit it stops.  Otherwise, it goes to the second source and if the candidates from it plus the candidates from the first source goes over the limit then it stops, and so on.

So that Heml goes for the next source only if it does not have enough candidates from the already processed sources.